# Can't import some simple functions in bash after set -a?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I have a file at `/tmp/variables.sh` which set functions and variables like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -a
foo=bar
reader() { "/users/avnamn/bin/reader4" "$@" ; }
pricer() { "/users/avnamn/bin/pricer" "$@" ; }
sget() { "/users/avnamn/bin/sget17" "$@" ; }
sourced=yes
```

and a script at `/tmp/script.sh` which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ "$sourced" != "yes" ]]
then
source "$(dirname "$0")/variables.sh"
fi
```

In bash I run:

```
$ cd "/tmp/"
$ source ./variables.sh
$ ./script.sh
```

and the shell responds like this:

```
bash: error importing function definition for `/users/avnamn/bin/pricer'
bash: error importing function definition for `/users/avnamn/bin/sget'
```

Why would it have trouble importing `pricer` and `sget`, but not `reader`?

Comment: You probably *also* have some *aliases* for `pricer` and `sget`.

Comment: Nicely caught, I did indeed have aliases to those in my bash_profile. Can you override those when setting a function? Or maybe the easiest thing is just to give the functions new names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `set -a` (aka `set -o allexport`) `bash` exports all *functions* declared thereafter in addition to variables.

The error indicates that `bash` can't *import* a function called `/users/avnamn/bin/pricer`, not `pricer`.

Most likely before running `source ./variables.sh`, you had run (possibly in one of your startup files):

```
alias pricer=/users/avnamn/bin/pricer
```

So when `source` read:

```
pricer() { "/users/avnamn/bin/pricer" "$@" ; }
```

It was transformed by the alias expansion to:

```
/users/avnamn/bin/pricer() { "/users/avnamn/bin/pricer" "$@" ; }
```

(which by the way creates a function that calls itself recursively).

You can define a function with such a name in `bash`, but `bash` won't let you export it. If you tried `export -f /users/avnamn/bin/pricer`, `bash` would report:

```
bash: line <n>: export: /users/avnamn/bin/pricer: cannot export
```

Still with `allexport`, the function *is* exported nonetheless (which you might argue is a bug), but subsequent `bash` shells invoked in that environment will refuse to import it, hence the message you get upon running `./script.sh` which starts a new `bash` invocation.

The exported function feature of bash is a very dangerous one (especially on systems where `sh` is `bash`!), it should be used sparingly.

The `allexport` feature is also quite dangerous (especially in `bash` which also exports functions) and something you would *not* want to do in an interactive shell.

Here, if want to export a number of variables to the environment without having to call `export` explicitly, I'd recommend you do:

```
set -o allexport
  A=1
  B=2
  ...
set +o allexport
```

(and make sure you don't declare functions in that section of code).

Aliases were the poor man's functions in csh that didn't have functions. In Korn-like shells, it's only useful for things that can't be done with functions, that is when you want to do some code transformation as opposed to defining some new command. They're also best avoided in most cases.